# dealing with array of characters . how can i define an array without declaring its size?

Tags: visual-c++

I have an assignment to write a c++ program that:

- declares an array named gamma of type char.
- declares an array named vowels of type char.
- prompts the user to input n characters in the array gamma.
- defines a function named save vowels that determines and return the number of vowels letters in the gamma array and save them in the vowels array.

I already tried to write this but I got many errors especially with gamma array.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    char gamma[];
    int i;
    cout<<"insert characterst//insert -1 when you finish "<<endl;

    while(i!=-1)
    {

        cin>>i;
        gamma[]='i';


    }

    char vowels[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};}
```

Comment: Can you list the errors you are getting?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to handle `char arrays` but not `char vectors`? If this is a **C++** assignment *and* you don't have the array dimensions specified you're nearly lost. If the task remains in that form, you need to define a maximum array size by yourself and handle array bounds check in your program.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic  .thank you so much! really!.. i really appreciate your help. i still just cant figure out the way i can define the array without declaring its size !!all the ways above didn't work! i do not know the size , the size will get declared when the user stops inserting the characters.. i'm still not sure about this ! ill really be grateful if you try to reexplain this part. like should i try the "dynamic allocation " thing to define the array ?! thanks again.

Comment: @fatima arrays have a fixed size that must be declared when the array is created. If you want something that can change size and grow as you need it to you should look at using [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You look to be well on your way.

> declares an array named gamma of type char.

```
char gamma[];
```

This part is almost correct although the array has a size of 0. If you wanted to give it a size of 10, you would change it to

```
char gamma[10];
```

> declares an array named vowels of type char.

This part is fine as is.

```
char vowels[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
```

The list automatically gives `vowels` a size of 5 and assigns the values.

> prompts the user to input n characters in the array gamma.

You look to have this down perfectly with the cout/cin lines. One small nitpick is that you should prefer using "\n" at the end of a cout instead of `endl` as it is much faster.

```
cout << "insert characterst//insert -1 when you finish\n";
```

You also need to change how you write to your array. You have to specify the index in which you want to write.

```
gamma[0] = 3; // Set the first element of gamma to 3
gamma[2] = 11;// Set the third element of gamma to 11
```

You'll need to add a counter to your while loop to know which position of `gamma` you are writing to

```
int counter = 0;
while(...) {
    cin >> i;
    gamma[counter] = i;
    counter++;
}
```

You also need to add a check to your while loop that makes sure you don't write past the end of your gamma array. **This is likely the cause of your errors.**

For example, if we gamma is defined with a size of 10 it can only hold 10 characters. Trying to write 11 characters to gamma will likely cause the program to crash. Try adding a check like:

```
while( i != -1 && counter < 10) // where 10 is capacity of gamma
```

> defines a function named save vowels that determines and return the number of vowels letters in the gamma array and save them in the vowels array.

You didn't give anything in your question on this point so I can't really help you out here.